# Notification on the bottom of the screen

Tags: support, ios-app

After upgrading to the newest version of ios-app I see strange notification on the bottom of the "select active application" screen. 
[image: bottom notification]
What is this?

Text "Доброе утро!" means "Good morning!" in Russian.

- App Version: 1.6.0.10
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.0.2 (Build 14A456)

Answer (score 4):

Apple shows that notification when you use an app in a specific location often. For example, when I arrive at work, suddenly the Stack Exchange app pops up on the bottom of the screen. When I come home, it shows WhatsApp. That's a feature.

I guess the SE developer who wrote this (Brian Nickel I guess), thought it was funny to greet you while you see this notification.

Comment: Is it possible to disable it? Where I can read more about this feature?

Comment: I am trying to find it, but I don't know.